# playonlinux - "Install components" tab is blank/unavailable/inaccessible/broken

Tags: wine, winetricks

The "Install components" tab is blank/unavailable/inaccessible/broken. How to fix it on playonlinux?

**NOTE:** I am using KDE 5.

Thanks! =D

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when the Internet has some sort of blockage (proxy, for example). To solve this we need a software for enabling anonymous communication and therefore go through this blockage.

The tor software protects you by bouncing your communications around a 
distributed network of relays run by volunteers all around the world: 
it prevents somebody watching your Internet connection from learning what 
sites you visit, it prevents the sites you visit from learning your physical location, and it lets you access sites which are blocked.

Install "tor" and "torsocks"...

```
pacman -S tor torsocks
```

... and start it with this command...

```
sudo -u tor /usr/bin/tor
```

Once that's done, you'll have a SOCKS proxy up and running that'll route anything it gets through tor. Many things (like PlayOnLinux) won't talk SOCKS. To solve this, you will use a light weight HTTP proxy called polipo to create a HTTP proxy wrapper for Tor's SOCKS proxy.

Install polipo...

```
pacman -S polipo
```

Then configure the proxy to chain to tor's SOCKS proxy modifying "/etc/polipo/config" configuration file...

```
cd /etc/polipo; cp config.sample config
```

... according to what is below...

```
allowedClients = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.0/24

socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
socksProxyType = socks5

proxyAddress = "0.0.0.0"
```

Disable the caching by adding...

```
diskCacheRoot = ""
```

... to the config, as this prevents polipo from filling up your disk and breaking the proxy.

Restart polipo, and now you should have both tor SOCKS HTTP proxy and polipo HTTP proxy...

```
systemctl restart polipo.service
```

On PlayOnLinux follow "Settings" -> "Internet" -> "Internet" and enable "Set a proxy".

For "Proxy address" inform...

```
127.0.0.1
```

... and for "Proxy port" inform...

```
8123
```

Restart PlayOnLinux!

**Done!**

**NOTE I:** This idea can be applied to any application able to use SOCKS or HTTP proxy!
**NOTE II:** The "pacman" is the Arch/Manjaro's package manager, but making the adaptations this guide will works on any Linux distribution!

Thanks! =D

**References:**

> https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2016/03/24/using-tor-as-a-http-proxy/ 
>   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polipo 
>   https://forum.manjaro.org/t/installing-and-running-tor-browser/9591 
>   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tor